# How to create an alternate path using the program NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

How can I create an alternate path and also a short path?

Comment: Not looking at the revision history, is there actually enough context to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem can be solved by looking at the primitives in the nw (network) extension. See *[NetLogo Nw Extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html)*.